# How can I force R.java generation for an Android Library (AAR)

Tags: android, android-resources, annotation-processing, aapt, aapt2

I'm building an Annotation Processor that uses the R Class to generate some additional Code.  This works fine for Android Applications

However, for Android Libraries (AARs), the R.java class is no longer generated.  AFAIK, the android library plugin generates an R.txt file, and then Android applications that depend on that library compile that R.txt information into the final R.java class.

My question is, is there a way I can force AAPT to create the R.java class for an AAR, so that my Annotation Processor can function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this, the final R file is in the app module, you can get the R.txt to get the mapping table, located in `build / intermediates / symbols / <flavor> /R.txt`.